# What redeem script is used in bitcoin core wallet when generate the address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, address, script, p2sh

I'm trying to generate the address `38DGj87axzmQiZeAd1w1y5FEmuu5a7pfBa` in my bitcoin core wallet with code.

First, I dump the private key from the address, then I calculate the address from the private key. As the address is start form `m`, which is of P2SH [bitcoin address type](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address). And the P2SH address is constructed as

```
base58-encode: [one-byte version][20-byte hash][4-byte checksum]
```

Here I don't know what the script used to calculate the `[20-byte hash]` in the bitcoin core wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `getaddressinfo` RPC command in the latest version of bitcoin core to get the hex encoded script for that address. But note that because you were able to get a private key, I assume this is a P2SH wrapped segwit address, which means the script is just an `OP_0` opcode followed by the hash160 of the public key corresponding to that private key.

Comment: I use bitcoin core 0.16.0 the latest version. But when I use `getaddressinfo` I got "Method not found"

Comment: Oh apologies, I thought it had made it into 0.16, it looks like its still only on the master dev branch. In that case you might have to create the script yourself using the OP_0 + hash160 approach I mentioned, see here for more info: https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/#creation-of-p2sh-p2wpkh-address

Comment: Use `validateaddress` instead (the parts of `validateaddress` that give address information are moved to a new `getaddressinfo` command for the next major version, 0.17).

Comment: @AndrewChow does validateaddress output the script? I wasn't sure if it did or if that was new functionality

Comment: @MeshCollider It does. The RPC was just split up in two in master, but no new functionality was added.

Answer (score 0):

*(For additional detail):*

It is a `P2SH-P2WPKH` (Pay to witness public key hash wrapped in a pay to script hash). To create this address for mainnet:

1. Create Witness `PKH`:

`PKH = OP_0 0x14 RIPEMD160(SHA256(compressed public key))`
`0x14` is number of bytes

2. Create `P2SH`:

`BASE58CHECK(0x05 PKH)`
`0x05` is the mainnet `P2SH` prefix